# Send Image as email attachement in android

Tags: android, sendmail, email-attachments

I am getting an error that i cannot attach empty file in gmail.I am trying to build simple app in which when i click on the button it show choices by which i can send image,But the below code is not working.
Please help i am novice in android.
code:

```
       if(view.getId()==R.id.SendImage)
       {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android:resource://com.example.jaspreet.intentstest.drawable/"+R.drawable.image);
        intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/image");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey i have attached this image");
        chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send Image");
        startActivity(chooser);

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
```

By using this the intent know that it will send .png file.

On [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) you can find a list of all media type/subtypes

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Bitmap b =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                b, "Title", null);

Uri imageUri =  Uri.parse(path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + C.PROJECT_PATH + "/drawable/" + R.drawable.icon_to_share);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
```

An android:resource:// is not a File, and probably you are messing up your Uri by converting to a File and then back to a Uri.

Comment: what is C.PROJECT_PATH here ?